# use powershell to grep through many large files

Tags: powershell, loops, grep

I have about 70 CSV files, all 1GB or so in size. On a windows environment I need to grep through them all to find specific lines.

My search file called "input.txt" contains these strings:

- CG234242424
- CG234234234
- CG234234235

In a Linux environment I would do this:

```
for line in `cat input.txt`; do grep $line *.csv >> output.txt; done;
```

How would I do this in Powershell?

Background - I'm a Linux guy, This is a once off request by the business users for an audit.

Comment: Take a look at [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd build a regular expression from the strings in the input file, and then use `Select-String` to check the CSV files for the presence of that pattern:

```
$re = (Get-Content 'input.txt' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
Select-String -Path '*.csv' -Pattern $re -CaseSensitive > 'output.txt'
```

But since PowerShell produces structured data rather than simple string output, you may want to make use of that structure:

```
$re = (Get-Content 'input.txt' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
Select-String -Path '*.csv' -Pattern $re -CaseSensitive |
    Select-Object Filename, LineNumber, Line |
    Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

If you must process each string from the input file separately you'd do it like this:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content 'input.txt') {
    Select-String -Path '*.csv' -Pattern $line -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive |
        Select-Object Filename, LineNumber, Line |
        Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType -Append
}
```

Comment: Went with option 3.  Perfect!